# Onesignal push notification only accept English language ones in Swift 3

Tags: ios, push-notification, swift3, push, onesignal

I have 2 segment in onesignal panel bir `EN` another `FR` but in my app have language change and people can change app language everytime in app inside , when I send push from one signal I send by segments but i want to add `appdelegate` inside language section if user language is English only must be alert English pushes , if user language France only must be alert France pushes.

In my app side language selection string is

```
let appcurrentlanguage = prefs.value(forKey: "lang") as! String
```

> How can I do it ?

My codes under below

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.


//HERE APP LANGUAGE

let appcurrentlanguage = prefs.value(forKey: "lang") as! String

            GMSServices.provideAPIKey("xxx")
            OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: "xxx") { (result) in

                let payload = result?.notification.payload

                if let additionalData = payload?.additionalData, let actionSelected = additionalData["comes"] as? String {
                    if actionSelected == "1" {

                        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
                        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
                        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                    }else if actionSelected == "2" {

                        if let newsID = additionalData["id"] as? String {
                           prefs.setValue(newsID, forKeyPath: "gelenID")
                            prefs.synchronize()
                        }

                        if let newsType = additionalData["type"] as? String {
                            prefs.setValue(newsType, forKeyPath: "newsType")
                            prefs.synchronize()

                        }





                    }
                }
              }


            sleep(2)
            return true
        }
```

Comment: i dont want to show English push messages when if user select language is French.  User language french i sent push messages from one signal to only French users but going push messages to French and English users I need to fix it.

Comment: When the user changes the app language, do you send the language code to the server (onesignal)? I've not used onesignal but I would imagine it requires this in order to determine the segments correctly.